# Is there a way to extract and/or translate summary.ordisurf output to view the relationship with each ordination axis in R?

Tags: r, vector-graphics, gam, vegan, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have a question regarding plotting and interpreting the relationship between continuous environmental variables to an [NMDS ordination](http://strata.uga.edu/8370/lecturenotes/multidimensionalScaling.html) of species abundances using R.

- This is a *programming* follow-up question to a [question on Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59257/80624) (stats.stackexchange).

In R's [vegan](http://127.0.0.1:10616/library/vegan/html/vegan-package.html) package, function [`envfit()`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/vegan/html/envfit.html) conveniently provides estimated coefficients for drafting a vector in 2-dimensional ordination space. This is convenient because we get a quantitative way to compare a given environmental variable to both axes of the ordination separately.

However, this really only works if the environmental variables have a linear relationship with the axes -- something again discussed in this [CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59257/80624). When the variables have a non-linear relationship to each ordination axis, another vegan function, [`ordisurf()`](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2011/06/10/what-is-ordisurf-doing/) can be used.

But instead of providing a direct quantitative relationship of the variable with each axis, `ordisurf()` instead simply provides summary output for a [gam model](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/07/30/gam/) fit overall.

Question: **Is there a way to extract and/or translate the `summary.ordisurf` output into the context of individual estimated coefficients for each ordination axis separately?**

- Vegan coauthor, Gavin Simpson, [encouraged me](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59170/nmds-and-variance-explained-by-vector-fitting/59257?noredirect=1#comment1116625_59257) to ask here on SO for an answer.

---

Below is example code (mostly [borrowed from Gavin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59257/80624)). `ordisurf` code:

```
require("vegan")
data(dune)
data(dune.env)

## fit NMDS using Bray-Curtis dissimilarity (default)
set.seed(12)
sol <- metaMDS(dune)

## NMDS plot
plot(sol)
## Fit and add the 2d surface
sol.s <- ordisurf(sol ~ A1, data = dune.env, method = "REML", 
                  select = TRUE)
## look at the fitted model
summary(sol.s)
```

This produces:

```
> summary(sol.s)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x1, x2, k = knots[1], bs = bs[1])
<environment: 0x2fb78a0>

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   4.8500     0.4105   11.81 9.65e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(x1,x2) 1.591      9 0.863  0.0203 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.29   Deviance explained =   35%
REML score = 41.587  Scale est. = 3.3706    n = 20
```

whereas `envfit()` would produce something separating the relationships with both axes (i.e., "NMDS1" and "NMDS2"):

```
envfit(sol ~ A1, data = dune.env)


***VECTORS

     NMDS1   NMDS2     r2 Pr(>r)  
A1 0.96473 0.26323 0.3649   0.02 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what you need. All information about the fit is in the returned gam object, and that is what you need to handle. However, for 2D model it is a thinplate spline gam which does not have such a simple interpretation of marginal responses. Neither should you want to have such an interpretation as it makes no sense (it is not rotation invariant). For fitted vectors (envfit) it is just a technical tool to help displaying linear trend surface on the plane. The info for axes is not rotation invariant, but the fitted plane is invariant w.r.t. configuration on 2D plane.

Comment: I'd misunderstood what you were looking for - @JariOksanen is quite right when he says you shouldn't be trying to decompose this into per axis components with NMDS. You could do that with PCA, CA, etc. but I thought you want to get values of the surface (i.e. predict from the GAM at a grid of points over the ordination). You can use `isotropic = FALSE` to allow for a more marginal interpretation (it would then use a tensor product smooth) but even with a TPRS you still evaluate the function over axis 1 for fixed value of axis 2. BUt really, don't do this for an NMDS

Comment: Hmm. Thanks to both of you for this feedback. My follow-up: *is* there an appropriate way to achieve my goal? Goal: Ito correlate environmental variables with each axis of an NMDS ordination so as to try to explain the distribution of points in NMDS space.